# Dynamic filename for file handler

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to set up a logger that will write a new timestamped log file every time the application is run in a specific directory.

for example what I am trying to do is

```
timestampFilename = time.strftime("runtimelog%b_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S.txt")
fh = logging.FileHandler(r'C:\my\folder\logs\'+timestampFilename, mode='w')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example tweeked from the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

```
import logging
import os
from datetime import datetime

# create logger with 'spam_application'
logger = logging.getLogger('MYAPP')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create file handler which logs in a specific directory
logdir = '.'
if 'APP_LOG_DIR' in os.environ:
    logdir = os.environ['APP_LOG_DIR']

logfile = datetime.now().strftime("run_%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S.log")

fh = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(logdir, logfile))
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.debug("my first log line")
```

The log directory may be configured with the environment variable `APP_LOG_DIR` and path names are built in a platform independent way thanks to [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html).

Comment: when I use this method i get
````OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ````
then it lists the full path

Comment: It is because you are on windows and : character is forbidden for file names. My fault, I'm on linux. I will update my answer changing name pattern.